# Sklearn во время обучения модели выдает ошибку "X and y have inconsistent dimensions (68180 != 6818)"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, машинное-обучение, sklearn

Вот мой код:

```
features = data.drop(["Tenure"], axis = 1)
target = data["Tenure"]
features = features.to_numpy()
target = target.to_numpy()
features_train, features_valid, target_train, target_valid = train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 12345)
features_train = features_train.reshape(-1, 1)
target_train = target_train.reshape(-1, 1)
model_elastic = ElasticNetCV(random_state = 12345)
model_elastic.fit(features_train, target_train)
predictions = model_elastic.predict(features_train)
print(accuracy_score(target, predict))
```

Ошибка:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-cb6d5d8978a1> in <module>
      7 target_train = target_train.reshape(-1, 1)
      8 model_elastic = ElasticNetCV(random_state = 12345)
----> 9 model_elastic.fit(features_train, target_train)
     10 predictions = model_elastic.predict(features_train)
     11 print(accuracy_score(target, predict))

~\anaconda3\envs\LikeProject\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_coordinate_descent.py in fit(self, X, y)
   1261 
   1262         if X.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
-> 1263             raise ValueError("X and y have inconsistent dimensions (%d != %d)"
   1264                              % (X.shape[0], y.shape[0]))
   1265 

ValueError: X and y have inconsistent dimensions (68180 != 6818)
```

Сначала у меня была ошибка с 2d массивом, но я решил её с помощью преобразования dataframe в numpy array и reshape, и после этого у меня и появилась эта ошибка. Мне нужно предсказать значения для target_train.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
features_train = features_train.reshape(-1, 1)
```

А зачем вы это делаете? Вы из матрицы тут делаете вектор. Я ещё понимаю, зачем это может делаться с таргетом, но с фичами этого делать точно не нужно. У вас в результате матрица фич размером 6818x10 превратилась в вектор длиной 68180 и модель просто не понимает теперь, как её сопоставить с таргет вектором длиной 6818.

Comment: Прежде всего, спасибо за ответ. Насчет проблемы, я её уже решил. Да, действительно, всё дело было в этой строке. Зачем я это сделал? До этой ошибки, была другая, sklearn говорил, что нужно превратить 2D массив в 1D с помощью reshape и на другом форуме у людей с такой же ошибкой этот способ помог, поэтому и добавил.

Comment: @Lorandius Видимо, это был совет для таргета, да, такое бывает нужно

Comment: Если вы решили проблему, то либо отметьте мой ответ как правильный, если дело в этом, либо напишите свой ответ, если дело в другом. Вопросы тут должны быть с ответами по возможности )